# Does a static_cast of a derived object to base always select most derived object?

Tags: c++, casting

In the artificial example below, if I `static_cast` to the base class, when I call the `setSnapshot()` function it still calls the actual object `setSnapshot()`.  This is what I want to happen.  My question is can I always rely on this to work?

In code I am working on, we have this class hierarchy and in the b class there are macros used which static cast to the b type.  This is to downcast from a base type so that specialised function in b can be called.

```
#include <iostream>

class a {

};

class b: public a {
public:
  virtual void setSnapshot() { std::cout << "setting b snapshot\n"; }
};

class c : public b {
public:
  virtual void setSnapshot() { std::cout << "setting c snapshot\n"; }
};

int main() {
   a* o = new c;

   //specifically casting to b
   static_cast<b*>(o)->setSnapshot(); //prints setting c snapshot - what I want to happen

   delete o;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aren't you forgetting `virtual void setSnapshot()=0;` in `class a`?

Comment: @barakmanos: Not needed; the code calls `b::setSnaphot`.

Comment: You aren't casting objects as the title of your question suggests. You are casting pointers.

Comment: @DanielDaranas you are right, wording was sloppy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title suggests that you're misunderstanding what the case does. `new c` creates an object of type `c`, and it will remain a `c` until it's destructed.

If you were to cast it to an `a`, you'd create a copy. But yu're only casting *pointers*. That doesn't affect the original object. That's still a `c`, and that's why you end up calling `c::setSnapshot()`.

Comment: But when you cast, are you not casting to the address of the start of the b part?  So my thinking was then you would call the b::setSnapshot().

Comment: @arcomber: That's the point of virtual functions. You point to the `b` part of a `c` object, which means the virtual methods in `b` will be overwritten by their equivalents in `c`.

Comment: Please explain your last comment or point me to a resource explaining.

Answer (score 2):

As long as a function is virtual in the statically known type a call of it will go to the override that is most derived.

For single inheritance this can be understood as a search for an implementation up the base class chain, starting in the most derived class.

In practice, for C++, the dynamic search is not done, and the effect of the search is instead implemented as a simple table lookup.